# How to navigate from subview to other view controller?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, addsubview, presentviewcontroller

Assume that I am having one view controller called MainPage(This is rootViewController). 
In that view controller , I am adding one sub view.

See Below :

```
FirstPage1=[[FirstPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstPage" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview:FirstPage1.view];
```

In that subview , I need to navigate to next page.

so that i have  used presentViewController like below code but its doen't worked well.

See Below Code:

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:AnotherViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It works well on first time but if I called for next time , I got below error.

Error :
whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Why are you adding the view of `FirstPage1` to itself? I already has its own view, it doesn't make any sense to add its own view once more...

Answer (score 0):

Having separate view controllers being linked together is a good use for `UINavigationController`. Just make a `UINavigationController` and add its view to self.view on your example. Then, do `[navController pushViewController: animated:]` for each view as needed. Or pop the last view controller, then push the new one if you don't want old pages to be accessible. From how your project seems to be set up, that's the easiest way.

Comment: In my project i  am adding ViewController(FirstPage) as a subview of ViewController(MainPage). I need to know how to navigate from subview to some other view.  i have already tried to added presentViewController to navigate some other viewcontroller . But its works for first cycle . If i did for next time i got the following error ." whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: If you add it just as a view to another view, you'll have to manually deal with views. Make your MainPage a UINavigationController instead! Then you can push/pop like I talked about rather than managing views yourself.